# Show Variable Products with a positive stock quantity in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I am using Simple and Variable products with active manage stock.

I need to list only products with stock quantity > 0 in frontend search and categories.

The follow code work ONLY with simple products.

How to fix code for use to list Variable Products too with parentStock > 0?

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_query_meta_query', 'show_only_products_with_qtdy_min_1', 10, 2 );
function show_only_products_with_qtdy_min_1( $meta_query, $query ) {
    if( is_admin() ) return $meta_query;

    // Add your criteria
    $meta_query[] = array(
        'key'     => '_stock',
        'type'    => 'numeric',
        'value'   => 0,
        'compare' => '>'
    );
    return $meta_query;
};
```